# I can't remove a jquery UI draggable after it has been dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a quiz set up at [this link](http://web.missouri.edu/~atgvyc/baby_names_root/baby_names.html) using jQuery UI draggable/droppable. It works fine -- except that users can't remove a card from a slot after it has already been dropped there. No matter where you drag a card, it goes right back to its slot.

I've been playing around with setting disabling the droppable on the out method, but it hasn't worked. Any thoughts on how to do this? Here's my JavaScript.

```
            $( ".card" ).draggable(
                {
                    revert: "invalid"
                }
            );

            $( ".slot" ).droppable(
            { 
                hoverClass: "ui-state-highlight",
                out: function(event, ui)
                {
                   // this isn't working
                   $(this).droppable({disabled: true, accept:""});
                },
                drop: function( event, ui ) 
                {
                    // to accept only one draggable at a time
                    $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', ui.draggable);
                    $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight")

                }
            });
```

Comment: Is .slot the only droppable area?

Comment: Well, there are six slots. And my fault, I forgot to include the link to the actual project. Here it is: http://web.missouri.edu/~atgvyc/baby_names_root/baby_names.html

Comment: When you drag an object from an area that it has been dropped. Make sure you remove the Class from the droppable area. Otherwise, it will normally stay disabled

Comment: Hmm. I added: $(this).removeClass("slot ui-droppable");  to the drop event. Still encountering the same problem. Strange why that isn't working.